# WinRT handling more than 5 touch simultaneous touch inputs

Tags: windows-runtime, multi-touch

How can more than five touch inputs be handled simultaneously on Windows Store Apps using C# and XAML? 
Different approaches have been tried, including this from MS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150606.aspx

Does any one know an approach to handle more than five?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you saying that your code is not informed of the sixth contact (on hardware that supports more than 5 contacts)? Or that you receive the sixth contact but your code doesn't know what to do with it?

Comment: Didn't think of the hardware limitation when I asked the question, but that's most likely it.

Comment: The code you linked to does not have a five-touch limit. It checks the `touchCapabilities.Contacts` property to determine the maximum number of hardware-supported touches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The five touch limit is most likely a hardware limitation. A touch screen has a dedicated processor to process the large amount of capacitance data. This processing results in a list of touches, and their respective locations, which is sent along to the operating system for handling.

In Apple-land, small iOS devices (iPhone, iPod) have a 5-touch limit, while large iOS devices (iPad) have a 10-touch limit.